# Null character within json

Tags: javascript, json

After an hour of googling I am kind of embarrassed to ask this. But are null characters (ascii null or `\0`) allowed within json? I can find that it's not allowed within json strings but my question is if it is allowed withing the body at all.

So is something like this valid:

```
{
    "MyKey": "MyValue"\0
}
```

Where the `\0` is an actual null character not an escaped one.

Comment: @Faust Read the question that isn't even close to what I'm asking

Comment: There are lots of online json validators

Comment: @charlietfl Which may or may not be correct. See for instance https://jsonlint.com/ where you can put in null chars into a json string it happily say it's valid when it isn't.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think it's so hard to put a literal null character into the above "MyValue" string and see it for yourself..

Comment: While the `\0` escape sequence is not permitted in JSON strings, there is nothing in the specification that prevents one from using the `\u0000` hex escape sequence to represent the NUL character within a string.

Comment: @EmileCormier yeah. To me that looks more like a loophole than a feature of the spec.

Comment: @debashish.ghosh For better or worse, the [WAMP protocol](https://wamp-proto.org/_static/gen/wamp_latest_ietf.html#rfc.section.15) happens to use that "loophole" to indicate that a JSON string is really a Base64-encoded binary byte array. This allows it to be transcoded to a MsgPack/CBOR byte string  (instead of a text string) when doing serialization conversions.

Comment: @debashish.ghosh I don't think allowing `\u0000` is any worse than allowing other non-printable characters to be encoded as `\uxxxx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to JSON specification JSON **cannot contain `\0`**, only spaces between tokens:

```
Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six
structural characters.

   ws = *(
           %x20 /              ; Space
           %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
           %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
           %x0D )              ; Carriage return
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159